# Google Charts Column chart - How can I show a tooltip when the value is so small the column height < 1 pixel?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am displaying some visualizations using Google Charts.

There is great variance in the data so some large numbers co-exist with small ones.  In the case of a [Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) this results in a scaling whereby some of the small values probably compute to less than one pixel of height and are thus invisible.

As a result there is no area to hover above, so I cannot show a tooltip.

Is anyone aware of a way to show a tooltip in this situation?

How about the white space above columns? Is there a way to include that as part of the hover region? I cannot find info about this in the [Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/) so it is unlikely, but maybe someone is aware of a way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the option `focusTarget: 'category',` you can achieve this. It's mainly used for displaying multiple values from the same "grouping" at the hAxis, but it fulfills your needs for this as well.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/dacs26ou/)